# Unfollowing people on instagram with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

i'm working on an instagram bot that involves unfollowing people.
It works with selenium by logging in, clicking on "Following" and then for each user it should click the unfollow button. There's the problem: when i try to click it, this exception occours:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button class="sqdOP  L3NKy _4pI4F   _8A5w5    " type="button">...</button> is not clickable at point (594, 155). Other element would receive the click: <span class="">...</span>


(Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.130)
```

There's my code:

```
    unfollow_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.sqdOP.L3NKy._8A5w5')

for button in unfollow_buttons:
    ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                    '.sqdOP.L3NKy._8A5w5')))
    button.click()
    ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[3]/button[1]')))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[3]/button[1]').click()
```

I understand that another item would receive the click, but i don't understand what item is it. Is there anybody who could help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody is seeing this, i fixed this in this way:

```
    unfollow_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.sqdOP.L3NKy._8A5w5')

for button in unfollow_buttons:
    if button.text == "Following":  
        ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                        '.sqdOP.L3NKy._8A5w5')))
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.move_to_element(button).click().perform()
        ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[3]/button[1]')))
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[3]/button[1]').click()  # UNFOLLOW CONFIRMATION
        time.sleep(1)
```